# how to combine a multi-result with a single result in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not sure if my title describes the problem correctly, but what I am trying to do is combine a list of error rates with a computed average and stddev, in 1 result set, so it can be easily graphed. Here are the queries in question:

```sql
select specific.POD, specific.DEFINITION, specific.error_rate as POD_JOB_RATE, general.error_rate as "General Rate for this JOB" from (
    select definition, total_run,failures,  round(failures/total_run,4) as error_rate from (
        select
        DEFINITION,
        count(*)                                           as total_run,
        count(case when state in (10, 15, 19) then requestid end) as failures
        from FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY group by DEFINITION
    ))  general
join (
    select POD, DEFINITION, round(failures/total_run) as error_rate from (
        select
        POD,
        DEFINITION,
        count(*)                                                  as total_run,
        count(case when state in (10, 15, 19) then requestid end) as failures
        from FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY group by POD, DEFINITION
    ) order by POD, DEFINITION, failures/total_run, total_run desc
)  specific
ON specific.DEFINITION = general.DEFINITION where specific.error_rate > general.error_rate order by POD;
```

Which produces:

| POD | DEFINITION | POD_JOB_RATE | General failure rate for all JOBS, on this POD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BDN | JobDefinition://apps/crmCommon/elasticSearch/UpdateDocumentsWhoseReferenceableContentHasChangedForEntityJobDef | 1 | 0.048 |
| BDN | JobDefinition://apps/crmCommon/elasticSearch/IndexActiveMetaModelVersionJobDef | 1 | 0.048 |
| BON | JobDefinition://bip/EssBipJob | 0.7742 | 0.0103 |
| BRY | JobDefinition://apps/psc/techStack/functionalSecurity/PscSecurityUpdateCredentialJob | 0.0769 | 0.0005 |
| BRY | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0005 |
| BUN | JobDefinition://apps/hcm/person/search/PersonKeywordSearch | 0.0755 | 0.0021 |
| CAAS | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/DueDateChecker | 1 | 0.0008 |
| CAAS | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0008 |
| CACG | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0004 |
| CADM | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0003 |

And, here is the query determining the `avg` and `stddev`

```sql
select avg(error_rate), stddev(error_rate) from (
    select failures/total_run as error_rate from (
        select
        DEFINITION,
        count(*)                                           as total_run,
        count(case when state in (10, 15, 19) then requestid end) as failures
        from FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY group by DEFINITION
    )
) avg_error_rate_by_jd;
```

Produces:

| ROUND(AVG(ERROR_RATE),4) | ROUND(STDDEV(ERROR_RATE),4) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0093 | 0.042 |

And what I'd like is:

| POD | DEFINITION | POD_JOB_RATE | General failure rate for all JOBS, on this POD | avg (all pods) | stddev (all pods) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BDN | JobDefinition://apps/crmCommon/elasticSearch/UpdateDocumentsWhoseReferenceableContentHasChangedForEntityJobDef | 1 | 0.048 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| BDN | JobDefinition://apps/crmCommon/elasticSearch/IndexActiveMetaModelVersionJobDef | 1 | 0.048 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| BON | JobDefinition://bip/EssBipJob | 0.7742 | 0.0103 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| BRY | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 0.0769 | 0.0005 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CAAS | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/DueDateChecker | 1 | 0.0008 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CAAS | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 0.0755 | 0.0008 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CACG | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0004 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CADM | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0003 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CADZ | JobDefinition://apps/sales/salesForecasting/forecasts/RefreshForecast | 1 | 0.0032 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |
| CADZ | JobDefinition://apps/crmCommon/core/standardImport/StandardImportMasterJob | 1 | 0.0032 | 0.0093 | 0.042 |

I feel like this is a special kind of join, but I could be completely off.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN`  the lower query to the upper query

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to `CROSS JOIN`, as the result of the overall calculations is a single row this will not multiply the final number of rows but will add both the wanted columns into each row.

```
SELECT
      specific.POD
    , specific.DEFINITION
    , specific.error_rate AS POD_JOB_RATE
    , general.error_rate AS "General Rate for this JOB"
    , oall.av_err_rate 
    , oall.sdev_err_rate
FROM (
    SELECT DEFINITION, total_run, failures, round(failures / total_run, 4) AS error_rate
    FROM (
        SELECT DEFINITION, count(*) AS total_run, count(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
        FROM FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
        GROUP BY DEFINITION
        )
    ) general
JOIN (
    SELECT POD, DEFINITION, round(failures / total_run) AS error_rate
    FROM (
        SELECT POD, DEFINITION, count(*) AS total_run, count(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
        FROM FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
        GROUP BY POD, DEFINITION
        )
    /* don't do this  ORDER BY POD, DEFINITION, failures / total_run, total_run  DESC */
    ) specific ON specific.DEFINITION = general.DEFINITION
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT avg(error_rate) av_err_rate , stddev(error_rate) sdev_err_rate
    FROM (
        SELECT failures / total_run AS error_rate
        FROM (
            SELECT DEFINITION, count(*) AS total_run, count(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
            FROM FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
            GROUP BY DEFINITION
            )
        )
    ) oall
WHERE specific.error_rate > general.error_rate
ORDER BY POD, DEFINITION;
```

**nb** don't use order by in the subqueries, it's a waste of effort, just use the final order by to control the result order.

Also: you could use "**window functions**" to simplify your query somewhat, e.g:

```
WITH error_rate
AS (
    SELECT POD
        , DEFINITION
        , COUNT(*) AS total_run
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) / COUNT(*) AS error_rate
    FROM FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
    GROUP BY POD
        , DEFINITION
    )
    , general_error_rate
AS (
    SELECT DEFINITION
        , AVG(error_rate) OVER (PARTITION BY DEFINITION) AS general_error_rate
    FROM error_rate
    )
    , overall_error_rate
AS (
    SELECT AVG(error_rate) OVER () AS av_err_rate
        , STDDEV(error_rate) OVER () AS sdev_err_rate
    FROM error_rate
    )
SELECT e.POD
    , e.DEFINITION
    , e.error_rate AS POD_JOB_RATE
    , g.general_error_rate AS "General Rate for this JOB"
    , o.av_err_rate
    , o.sdev_err_rate
FROM error_rate e
JOIN general_error_rate g ON e.DEFINITION = g.DEFINITION
CROSS JOIN overall_error_rate o
WHERE e.error_rate > g.general_error_rate
ORDER BY e.POD, DEFINITION;
```

and even that can be combined to reduce passes through the data:

```
WITH error_rate
AS (
    SELECT POD
        , DEFINITION
        , COUNT(*) AS total_run
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS error_rate
        , AVG(COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY DEFINITION) AS general_error_rate
        , AVG(COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) OVER () AS av_err_rate
        , STDDEV(COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) OVER () AS sdev_err_rate
    FROM FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
    GROUP BY POD
        , DEFINITION
    )
SELECT POD
    , DEFINITION
    , error_rate AS POD_JOB_RATE
    , general_error_rate AS "General Rate for this JOB"
    , av_err_rate
    , sdev_err_rate
FROM error_rate
WHERE error_rate > general_error_rate
ORDER BY POD, DEFINITION;
```

**ps** `* 1.0` introduced to ensure decimal results

Comment: `* 1.0` is unnecessary. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0g5spY8K)

Comment: well, both you and @MTO have solution. I ran a cardinality check on them, and they differ by 11594 - 11498. Less than 100 from a data set of 35829800. I have no way to know which is accurate or why there is a discrepancy. Both run between 3.3 and 3.6 seconds

Comment: Are you sure that using `AVG` to calculate the general error rate is correct? The output differs from the results of the OP's query in the question [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yH_766pr).

Comment: No, it was an overzealous use of AVG.

Answer (score 3):

Don't `JOIN`, use analytic functions to perform the "general" calculation and to calculate the average and standard deviation:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT pod,
         definition,
         pod_job_rate,
         general_job_rate,
         AVG(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN general_job_rate END) OVER () AS avg_all_pods,
         STDDEV(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN general_job_rate END) OVER () AS stddev_all_pods
  FROM   (
    SELECT pod,
           definition,
           ROUND(failures/total_run, 4) AS pod_job_rate,
           ROUND(
             SUM(failures) OVER (PARTITION BY definition)
             / SUM(total_run) OVER (PARTITION BY definition),
             4
           ) AS general_job_rate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY definition ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
    FROM   (
      SELECT pod,
             definition,
             COUNT(*) AS total_run,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN state IN (10, 15, 19) THEN requestid END) AS failures
      FROM   FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
      GROUP BY
             pod,
             definition
    )
  )
)
--WHERE  pod_job_rate > general_job_rate
ORDER BY pod;
```

Alternatively, you can do it entirely with analytic functions (and no aggregation functions):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT pod,
         definition,
         pod_job_rate,
         general_job_rate,
         avg_all_pods,
         STDDEV(CASE def_rn WHEN 1 THEN general_job_rate END) OVER ()
           AS stddev_all_pods
  FROM   (
    SELECT pod,
           definition,
           ROUND(
             AVG(
               CASE
               WHEN state IN (10, 15, 19) AND requestid IS NOT NULL
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
               END
             ) OVER (PARTITION BY pod, definition),
             4
           ) AS pod_job_rate,
           ROUND(
             AVG(
               CASE
               WHEN state IN (10, 15, 19) AND requestid IS NOT NULL
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
               END
             ) OVER (PARTITION BY definition),
             4
           ) AS general_job_rate,
           ROUND(
             AVG(
               CASE
               WHEN state IN (10, 15, 19) AND requestid IS NOT NULL
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
               END
             ) OVER (),
             4
           ) AS avg_all_pods,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pod, definition ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY definition ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS def_rn
    FROM   FILTERED_REQUEST_HISTORY
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
WHERE  pod_job_rate > general_job_rate
ORDER BY pod;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GXQzXLNu)

Comment: That last query runs for 5 minutes before I finally terminate it.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Then just use the first query.

Comment: obviously :) It was more of an FYI

Comment: So, your first query, which you seem to have modified from the other day, and it's original form, both produce a different answer for the generalized avg. A simple computation of average produces yet another value. 

Your most recent says the overall avg is 0.0574, the original query says it's 0.0146 and simple computation of average produces 0.0179

I suppose the original question has been answered, but the values I have now I don't know what to make of.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno You need to generate a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that you can manually calculate what the answer should be and test the solutions. I've tried to do that in the fiddle linked in the answer so that my queries get the same output as your queries but we do not have your sample data so we cannot properly test it (which is why you providing a [MRE] is important).

Comment: Yup, I am going to get that data and probably post another question since the original question is answered.